# How do I know what type of object is in a firebase database in java for android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a map of objects from a Firebase database in Android Dtudio.

```
mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Map<String, Double> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
        double  amount = map.get("Total");
        Log.v("E_Value", " Data : " + dataSnapshot.getValue());         
         total.setText(Double.toString(amount));
    }
}
```

Here I have declared to get me a double, but the problem is that sometimes this amount can be an integer.
So if I put 5 instead of 5.0, then I will get an error. How do I make it so that it I know what kind of object it is, and make it retrieve either one correctly?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which you can solve this. One would be to make sure to add in your database only `Double` values, which make sense because if neeed a double, the correct way is to store it as a `5.0` not as an Integer `5`. The second way would be to use define your map as `Map<String, Object>`, but in this case make sure to cast the result to a Double if the result is a Double.

Answer (score 0):

ToString is automatically being called on your object. After that occurs the system is auto casting to the closest match.
You should just be able to explicitly cast the type that is returned (if you know it will be a numeric type) just do the following :

```
Double.parseDouble(map.get[“Total”])
```